# Not getting frequency values in webaudio-api

Tags: web-audio-api, frequency-analysis

I am using this spectrogram.js from github to plot spectrogram and obtain frequency values in real-time.
[Github Repo](https://github.com/miguelmota/spectrogram)

I have written this extra stopSong function:

```
function stopSong() {
 var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
 var ctx = new AudioContext();
  var osc = ctx.createOscillator();
  osc.connect(ctx.destination);
  osc.start(0);



spectro.stop();
 var freqData= new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
 analyser.getByteFrequencyData(freqData);
 //var f = Math.round(freqData[1]);
 //  var text = f + ' Hz';
  var idx = 0;
                for (var j=0; j < analyser.frequencyBinCount; j++) {
                    if (freqData[j] > freqData[idx]) {
                        idx = j;
                    }
                }
   var frequency = idx * ctx.sampleRate / analyser.fftSize;
                console.log(frequency);



  //document.getElementById("frec").innerHTML = text;


             }
```

But everytime i am running it it give 0 as output. Can anybody tell whats wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the `oscillator` to the `analyser`:

`oscillator.connect(analyser);`

Also you might want to call `getByteFrequencyData` multiple times, maybe in `requestAnimationFrame`, or something like `setTimeout`.